# how to find result in mysql if column have comma saperated value and contain any character of string

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I want a select query in mysql. I have a table name delivery_area and have one column name start_with_zip_postal. column have value with comma separated like 100,101 and now i want to search a result I have a postal code 101245 now i want to search if  start_with_zip_postal have any matches string of 101245 
now one row will retrieve because column have 101 value in mysql 
for better under standing please check my table structure in screenshot
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find_in_set` like below query :

```
select * from deleivery_areas where find_in_set(substring('101245',1,3),start_with_zip_postal);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FIND_IN_SET instead of LIKE.

```
SELECT * FROM delivery_areas WHERE FIND_IN_SET(LEFT('101245',3), start_with_zip_postal);
```

To search in comma separated values in MySQL we can to use FIND_IN_SET.

Comment: Have you checked this? I checked this and it is working.

Comment: @Pradeep I agree with Rahul. How will `101245` match `100,101`?

Comment: @Pradeep FIND_IN_SET checks for a complete string in comma separated string ex :
`SELECT FIND_IN_SET('101', '101,102');` will output 1 but
`SELECT FIND_IN_SET('101245', '101,102');` will output 0

Comment: @Rahul I know find in set will check with complete string.
I just thought that user wants to match complete string now i read the question again and got the point.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your data so that each prefix is in a different row. Create a table `delivery_area_zip_prefix`

```
CREATE TABLE delivery_area_zip_prefix (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    delivery_area_id INT,
    starts_with_zip_postal VARCHAR(16),
    CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (delivery_area_id) REFERENCES delivery_area (id)
);
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM delivery_area AS d
JOIN delivery_area_zip_prefix AS p ON d.id = p.delivery_area_id
WHERE LOCATE('101245', p.starts_with_zip_postal) == 1
```

Comment: characters are not fixed 3 it can be 2,4 and more

Comment: please edit your question and ask clearly @Expert Team

Comment: @ExpertTeam Then you really need to normalize the schema. I don't think there's a way to do that with a comma-separated list in MySQL.